Proxying legacy IIS App with Yarp on the same base path
I'm running a legacy IIS app which has some accompanying .net core apps. These apps are currently running via kestrel on their individual ports. With a growing number of apps, maintaining firewall rules becomes a hassle, so the idea of using Yarp as a reverse proxy in between was born.
Let's say the IIs app runs on http://localhost/MainApp, app1 runs on http://localhost:5001/, app2 on http://localhost:5002 and so on.
What I would like to have is the proxy redirecting http://localhost/MainApp/SideApps/App1 to http://localhost:5001 and http://localhost/MainApp/SideApps/App2 to http://localhost:5002 and so on.
This is actually working fine with yarp listening on http://+:80 using http.sys.
But I'm having trouble with the MainApp: I do not know how to setup Yarp that request to that don't get redirected at all, but instead be served by the IIS app.
I tried setting up a catch-all route, but that causes recursive redirections.
How can I setup Yarp in a way that if no route for the request matches, it get's served by the default IIS app?
I swear I had this working at some point, but coming back to this months later I cannot get it done.

Then your YARP instance should bind to the right reserved URL, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/https-binding#reserved-urls like http://+:80/MainApp/SideApps and then IIS can handle http://+:80/MainApp for you. But there isn't any necessity to run ASP.NET Core apps on their own, and why didn't you run all of them on IIS behind ASP.NET Core module?

Thanks, that works! Strictly speaking, that's not an answer to the original question, but for me it's a working solution - and that's what I was after. Thank you very much.
